# Google Play in-app purchase box doesn't launch within the context of the activity that starts the subscriptions flow, Android Billing Library V55

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

Integrated the Google Play Billing Library version 5 into an existing application.
when trying to start the purchase flow using launchBillingFlow() method and passing an instance of the current activity which is supposed to be the Activity from which the billing flow will be launched.
               `billingManager.launchBillingFlow(activity,SKU);`
what happends is that the purchase box doesn't lauch within the activity, what happens seems like a new fragment or activity is created and the purchase box is launched within that activity.

I don't know why it's behave like that. when trying to inspect the layout through the LAYOUT INSPECTOR tool in android studio it shows a blank screen.
[image][image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I created a bran new project and the same code works pretty well as expected.
that only happens when trying to integrate the feature to an existing application.
I also created a brand new Activity within the existing application and made it the launcher activity to test the subscription button and the problem is still there.

Comment: Afaik, this has been the intended behaviour from the beginning since the Google Play shows its own UI component to present the payment/purchase bottom sheet.

Comment: @Darshan yes, but it's supposed to be launched within the Activity or The fragment which starts the purchase flow. if you looked at the gif attached above you will notice that the bottom sheet doesn't appear in the same Activity (Subscription Activity).